# How to solve the grid view problem in flutter?

Tags: flutter, listview, gridview, flutter-gridview

I have a problem of grid view. I add lists as described in 1st screenshot, then the same list will be updated on the another page (as per second screen shot). However, as you can see overflow error, that is happening and I can not solve that. So, can you guys explain how to increase it's height as I add element in the lists. Hope, it is clear.

[image]
[image]

Comment: How do you expect us to help if you don't show your code of the screen that goes wrong?

Comment: Just Use Listview Builder

Comment: you can check code just below, Sorry, for not explained whole before

Answer (score 0):

use childAspectRatio like example below :
gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(

```
    childAspectRatio: 0.4,
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply, but as you told, I applied that, but that is going to be fix height, however, I want this height increase as we increase number of list. (you can see screenshot below)

```
Consumer<HomeProvider>(
                  builder: (context, provider, child) => GridView.builder(
                      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: provider.allData.length,
                      gridDelegate:
                          SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisCount: provider.isPress ? 2 : 1,
                          childAspectRatio: 0.4
                        
                      ),
                      itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                        return provider.allData[index];
                      }))`enter code here`
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brq6U.png)

Comment: is that grid has parent widget like column  ?